# How to undo $( "button" ).remove()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using JQuery's

```
$( ".button" ).remove();
```

method to remove all buttons from my page on right after user clicks print PDF button which converts the HTML Page to PDF. However, after that operation is complete I want the button to be inserted again without refreshing the page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: insert the element again at its original position, you don't have an *undo*

Comment: why you are removing it when you want it back? You can simply hide and show it again

Comment: can you show all the function

Comment: `$( ".button" ).hide()` and `$( ".button" ).show`

Comment: `hide` and `show` will probably suffice. _But_, if you absolutely need it gone from the DOM (which you might depending on how your PDF generation is happening), you want `detach`. The example on the page is pretty much exactly what you're trying to do: https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: You can use css style to hide these button from printout.

Comment: You can either use show/hide, or print-specific media queries to hide the buttons in print mode (if that's how the PDF generation is done), or you could detach the element but keep a reference to the button in a variable (wrapped in a jQuery object) and then re-append it to the DOM when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want it back you dont need to remove them but hiding them will be better.

```
$(".button").hide();
```

when you want them back say you wanna have them back after the pdf button clicked so in this clause

```
$(".button").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `display` functionality in css, that is in your css

```
.button {
   display:inline;
}
```

In your javascript, I see you using jQuery, you just change this:
To remove:

```
$('.button').css('display', 'none');
```

To return back:

```
$('.button').css('display', 'inline');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger for all button with a button. Try `toggle` function.

```
   $(".toggleButton").click(function(){
        $(".button").toggle();
    });
```